# How to force httpd to use rh-php56 from red hat software collections

Tags: apache, rhel7, software-collections

Anyone have any luck with making httpd use rh-php56 from the Red Hat Software Collections?

I see documentation on how to enable the newer version of php at the CLI...but not for making Apache use the new version of PHP installed via the rh-php56 package.

(I should clarify --  this is for a RHEL 7.x box)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rh-php56 provides mod_php only for httpd24 (not for base system)

Simpler way is to use php-fpm (which also allow to run apache in threaded mode)

See:

- http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2014/08/01/Apache-httpd-server-2.4.10-and-PHP-FPM-5.6-in-Fedora-21
- http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2014/03/28/PHP-FPM-and-HTTPD-2.4-improvement

To summarize above post, use in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm is mod_php not available
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have there been any new developments around this? I am struggling with the same problem on CentOS 7, not being able to have `httpd` make use of `rh-php56`. I'd prefer not to have to redirect requests through php-fpm, it seems wrong? Or am I just being too ocd about this...

Comment: IMHO mod_php should die ;) FPM is much better for security (separate process), and for performance (allow to run apache in thread mode).

Answer (score 1):

Add the LoadModule command to your httpd.conf and point it to the php56 module from RHSCL:

```
LoadModule php5_module /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/librh-php56-php5.so
```

This generally seems to work for me, but I have only tested basic page rendering. I wouldn't be surprised if there are some bugs related to loading a Special Collections module in the regular Apache config. After all, RH Special Collections packages intentionally install to a completely different part of the filesystem to avoid conflicts. You may want to consider using HTTPD24 from the RHSCL along with PHP56 to avoid configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had to deal with upgrading to php56 for some PHP webapps on a RHEL 7 machine. I looked into the httpd24 route and for some reason it seems much simpler to just use the stock `nginx` RHEL package with `rh-php56-php` and `rh-php56-php-fpm`.

1. Install the `rh-php56-php` packages you need
2. enable and start the `rh-php56-php-fpm` systemd service and configure `php-fpm` in `/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/` (i.e., edit the `php-fpm.conf` and `php-fpm.d/www.conf` files). You'll need to decide if you want php-fpm to listen on a unix socket or via TCP at the minimum and it's also a good idea to configure logging properly to help troubleshoot.
3. Configure nginx to proxy to your php-fpm unix socket or TCP address, e.g., `localhost:9000`. There's plenty of googleable resources on nginx configuration for php-fpm and Drupal / Mediawiki / Wordpress / etc.